# How to detect the presence of a simple but translucent shape?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm quite new to OpenCV and CV as a whole. I'm trying to create a state detector that allows me to extract information from the screen in a certain game. This feature pre-processing is almost complete, but up until now I have used colour as the main way of extracting useful information. I wish to capture as to whether this red shield shape is present in the screen:
([image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/537774605365149716/537786159103737869/unknown.png])

The shield is always shaped like this, but is translucent and so the colour test cannot be applied.

I have not yet tried a solution, as after much searching and learning, for this one problem I'm not sure where to start.

I have an image `processedImage`, and would like to extract a simple bool describing whether this shape is present or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know that the shield is always red, convert the image into HSV and use the hue channel to threshold/hysteresis the image and get the red region

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

m = cv2.split(hsv)
plt.imshow(m[1])
```

Plotting the Saturation channel here just for visualization purposes. Once you get this, perhaps you can use some sort [template matching algorithm](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) to get the location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I will definitely look into this. Luckily, I don't need to get its location, just its presence. I do actually capture red regions already for another state, but I suppose I could test a different copy of the image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to detect the edges of the shield image. You can do this through some image processing techniques at:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html#py-table-of-content-imgproc

Perhaps something like:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200) #img is your image
```

Would work for you, but if using the color image doesn't work you can try converting to greyscale first with something like:

```
grey = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) #screen is your image
```

And then do the edge detection algorithm.
Obviously once you find the shape you would have to define it (likely through tweaking the Canny parameters, or doing some other technique like HoughLines), but to do this it would be helpful first to think about things like

1. Is the shield always in the same area of the screen?
2. Is it always the same size?
3. Are there any other defining characteristics you can think of?

Then craft your algorithm around these assumptions! I think you would want to define a function and have it `return True` or `return False` and then you can call this to "get a boolean of if the image is present"
Because you're not asking an explicit question I think this answer will be sufficient, but feel free to drop a comment if it needs elaboration! Otherwise, if this answered your question, then to accept it you can click the check mark next to the post :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I am knowledgeable enough about OpenCV to know about edge detection using Canny, though of course when you don't know what you don't know, it's best to say you're a novice. The shield moves around the screen, that makes it more difficult. But it stays the same size. It appears only for a small amount of frames. Whilst using edge detection is a good idea, I struggle to use this information to construct an algorithm that would work well enough. Perhaps test against an existing image of the shield? Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. I think that a tutorial I found the other day at : https://pythonprogramming.net/open-cv-basics-python-plays-gta-v/
may be useful for you to look at. He uses CV to detect the edge of the roads, but I think the procedure may be similar to what you're trying to do. At the very least I think it will give you an idea where you want to go!